# Pushwoosh iOS SDK, disable alert generated by pushwoosh in Background mode

Tags: ios, pushwoosh

I want to disable alert generated by pushwoosh manager when i received notification when my app is in background mode. I have tried both Pushwoosh_SHOW_ALERT and Pushwoosh_ALERT_TYPE, it works fine in foreground mode. But i want to show custom message to user when received notifications.

Answer (score 0):

When the app is in background the alert is generated by iOS itself by default.

You might want to deliver the notification silently and present notification yourself. See this article on how to achieve that:
http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/deletable-ios-push